# Select only content that's needed

Tags: excel, vba

I've created an Excel document with a sheet, named "Plakken". This sheet contains a button which paste a table, that the user copied from an intranet page, on to the sheet "Template (2)".

In the example below, you can see the table on "template (2)" 
What i like to do now, is copy some data from the pasted table to sheet "opslaan", the data i want to copy is:

1. Artikelnummer (article number)
2. Artikelnaam (article name)
3. datum (date)

These are the 3 left columns, for example:

[image]

But the data in the table is seperated with rows containing the word "vulgebied".

Example:

[image]

[image]

I'm searching for a way to only copy all the data listed above, and paste them on the sheet "opslaan".

The table is different every time, sometimes there are more or few lines between the "vulgebied" row, but the style of the table is always the same.

Edit:

I think something that might work is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRow()

Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1) 
    For i = 100000 To 1 Step -1 
        With .Cells(i, "C")         
            If .Value = "Vulgebied" Then             
                If rng Is Nothing Then 
                    Set rng = .Cells
                Else
                    Set rng = Application.Union(rng, .Cells)
                End If
             End If
        End With
    Next i

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
End With

End Sub
```

But because the word "vulgebied" contains a different number after the word, i don't know how to solve that..

Example: https://files.fm/u/n4k4z6yz

Comment: Pls include the code you tried

Comment: At the moment i only have the code that pastes the table in to the sheet "template (2)". I don't know how to go further, because of the seperations between the lines i want to copy. I hope someone here can help me solve that problem.

Comment: @RickA. look at the answer and modified code below

Answer (score 0):

In order to find cells that might contain the word `"Vulgebied"`, use the function `Instr`.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRow()

Dim i As Long
Dim DelRng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template (2)")

    For i = 100000 To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(.Range("C" & i).Value, "Vulgebied") > 0 Then
           If DelRng Is Nothing Then
               Set DelRng = .Range("C" & i)
           Else
               Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Range("C" & i))
           End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.EntireRow.Delete
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

**Note**: a safer way to make sure `"Vulgebied"` is found within a cell is by using the `LCase` function (converts the all characters of the word to lower case), see below:

```
If InStr(LCase(.Range("C" & i).Value), "vulgebied") > 0 Then
```

Comment: An alternate case-insensitive method would be to use the `vbTextCompare` option with `InStr`. I dunno which would be more efficient.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld never bench-marked it, would be interesting.